# Pipe audio from VLC to stdout?

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, codec, flv

I want VLC to play some video (from VLC), but have the audio be outputted to stdout or a file. Here's what I've been trying to do, but it obviously doesn't work. It's a FLV file btw:

```
DISPLAY=:0 vlc -I rc --extraintf qt4 TheMatrix :sout=#transcode{vcodec=flv,vb=1024,fps=24,acodec=flv,ab=128,channels=2}:duplicate{dst=std{access=file,mux=ts,dst=-}} | socat - TCP:192.168.1.3:2098
```

Comment: You would have to extract the audio stream as soon as it is demuxed from the video, and before it is decoded.  gtstreamer might be the more appropriate tool.

Comment: @sawdust Any suggestions on how to do this?